# RavenDB: How do you update child entities?

Tags: parent, ravendb

I have been playing around with RavenDB.  I have to say I am quite impressed, but I am struggling to understand how to update child objects.  For example, lets say we have the following:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public Student()
    { 
        Courses = new Collection<Course>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to save one Student and two Courses associated to the student in the database.  I am able to load the Student with the two Courses without a problem as well.  But when I tried to modify the courses, for example student.Courses.Add(new Course { Id = 5, Title = "Accounting 101"}), I was expecting it to sync between what is in the database versus what is currently in student.Courses.  Basically, I am expecting it to delete the courses in the database and only have the course in student.Courses.  This maybe my misunderstanding of how RavenDB works.  I couldn't find any examples like this.  What is the best practice way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't do any of what you described.  The way you have modeled it, there are two separate documents in the database:

```
Course
{
  Id : "courses/1",
  Title : "Algebra"
}

Student
{
  Id : "students/1",
  Name : "John",
  Courses :
    [
      {
        Id : "courses/1",
        Title : "Algebra"
      }
    ]
}
```

The benefit of denormalizing `Course` into `Student` is that you don't have to load `Course` documents when reviewing `Student` information to get the course's title.

The down side is that any changes to `Course` must be done to both documents.  If you just add a course to the student document, it is referring to a `Course` document that doesn't exist.  Raven won't stop you from doing that.  There are no referential integrity constraints in a document database.

In the real world, you would probably add a course before you add the course to a Student, and dropping all students from a course doesn't mean that there is no course.  So really, it's only actions like renaming a course that have to go touch both the course document and all student documents that have the relationship.

Often you will want to just use `IList<string> CourseIds`.  There is no requirement that you denormalize.  Review [this documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships) for further details.